# How to enable the onclick event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I used the following code to disable the onclick event .
present code

```
function moveToDeckTable(game_table_id,category_id,status){
    var_game_table_id=game_table_id;
    var redirect="table.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ahr/addPlayer.php",
        data: {game_table_id:game_table_id,status:status},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success==1){
                PlayingStatus =setInterval(setPlayingStatus,1000);
                open_game_window = window.open(redirect+"?id="+data.game_table_id,"","_blank");
            }    
            else if(data.success==0)
                alert("User already playing..");
            else if(data.success==2)
                alert("You have not enough coins to play in this table .buy more coins or play in minor coins table.");    
        }
    }); 
    //code to disable onclick

}
function setPlayingStatus(){
    if(open_game_window.closed){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ahr/setPlayingStatus.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                clearInterval(PlayingStatus);
            }
        }); 
        //code to re enable onclick
    }    
}
```

---

Now , I want to enable that event again on another button click. How can I enable the onclick event?

Comment: How did that event attach to that element at start? It use `onclick` or `$(ele).on('click')`?

Comment: is there another way to disable enable the onclick event?

Comment: Why disable it? I'm writing an answer right now ;)

Comment: @ fuyushimoya   onclick

Comment: Ok, just one question. How many of these clickable elements do you have? How many buttons are you wanting to link to these function/click events?

Comment: i have a button with its unique id which is depends on database's value and how many buttons is not final its depends on database. i just want to open new window on button click and if one window opened i want to disable the button so user cant be able to open more than one window.and when user close the window onclick will be re enable.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. It doesn't need you to cancel or "reinitialize" events at all.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //capture the click event
  var eventsEnabled = true;

  var log = document.getElementById('log');

  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    //if capturing events is true
    if (eventsEnabled == true) {
      log.innerHTML = 'event captured';
    }
  };



  document.getElementById('captureStop').onclick = function() {
    eventsEnabled = false;
    log.innerHTML = 'capturing turned off';
  };

  document.getElementById('captureStart').onclick = function() {
    eventsEnabled = true;
    log.innerHTML = 'capturing turned on';
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="This is a button">
<input type="button" id="captureStop" value="Stop the evil clicking (capturing)">
<input type="button" id="captureStart" value="Start the evil clicking (capturing)">
<div id="log"></div>
```

**UPDATE:**
There is really no way for me to test this code, so you will have to tell me if it works or not. You/I will improve it from there and conclude this issue.

This is some of your existing code. We need to toggle disable the functions. It appears simple enough. Just adapt the code in my "old" answer to function for this purpose.

```
function moveToDeckTable(game_table_id,category_id,status){
    if(captureEvents == true){//your if (see my first answer [above])
    var_game_table_id=game_table_id;
    var redirect="table.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "ahr/addPlayer.php",
        data: {game_table_id:game_table_id,status:status},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success==1){
                PlayingStatus =setInterval(setPlayingStatus,1000);
                open_game_window = window.open(redirect+"?id="+data.game_table_id,"","_blank");
            }    
            else if(data.success==0)
                alert("User already playing..");
            else if(data.success==2)
                alert("You have not enough coins to play in this table .buy more coins or play in minor coins table.");    
        }
    }); 
    //code to disable onclik
  }
}
function setPlayingStatus(){
    if(captureEvents == false){
    if(open_game_window.closed){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "ahr/setPlayingStatus.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                clearInterval(PlayingStatus);
            }
        }); 
        //code to re enable onclik
    }  
   }   
}
```

Comment: in my code  i used "game_table_id" in selector that is passed by function parameter so i need to use onclick function insted .onclick.

Comment: Could you better explain why this code isn't going to work for you? I'm sorry, I don't understand the different between `onclick` and `.onclick`.

Comment: I will revise my answer if it doesn't work for you ;)

Comment: Ok, just one question. How many of these clickable elements do you have? How many buttons are you wanting to link to these function/click events?

Comment: i have dynamic button list like button18 ,button19 etc not final. i just want like on button click open new window and if one window opend i want to disable the onclick so user cant be able to open more than one window .and when window closed i will re enable the onclick so user able to re open the window.

Comment: is there any other way to set limited window open with window.open().I have to do all this because of limited window only.

Comment: See this article about window.open and what you can do with it http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/openclose.shtml I haven't had a need for windows so I don't know many of the functions available to the window object in this way.

Comment: See my updated answer. You just need (if possible) to implement my first answer to determine if it is "valid" to open the window.

Comment: I think i can solve my issue with your old code .thanks i will update you with my new working code.

Comment: Great, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function enable(){
$( "body" ).delegate( '#btn'+game_table_id+' > .green_btn', "click", function() {
// your code
});
}
```

onClick of other function call enable function it add event for the button

Answer (score 0):

Working code.
@www139 thanks the updated code. 
[image: function1-disable the onclick if captureEvents true]

[image: function2-enable the onclick if captureEvents false]